# WSL File permission problems on docker-compose mounted volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, wsl-2

I'm using docker-compose in a `WSL` environment. I noticed some of the files created by the running docker container show up as user=root and group=root. How can I change the docker-compose to create new files under my current UID and GID?

I noticed that in the `WSL` bash shell I can delete files owned by root:root as a regular user without sudo. Conversely the running docker containers can't delete files, even if the file wasn't owned by root.

The files are at `/mnt/c/projects-new/...` or in Windows at `c:\projects-new`.

/etc/wsl.conf

```
[network]
generateResolvConf = true
```

Before you ask, metadata for Linux perms is defined in `/etc/fstab`:

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs / ext4 defaults 0 0
C: /mnt/c drvfs defaults,metadata 0 0
```

I'm using `Win 10 20H2 (OS Buidl 19042.928) WSL Version 2`

cat /etc/*release

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

My `docker-compose.yml` file is as below:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  ssc-file-generator-db2-test:
    container_name: "ssc-file-generator-db2-test"
    image: ibmcom/db2:latest
    hostname: db2server
    privileged: true
    env_file: ["acceptance-run.environment"]
    ports:
      - 50100:50000
      - 55100:55000
    networks:
      - back-tier
    restart: "no"
    volumes:
      - setup-sql:/setup-sql
      - db2-shell-scripts:/var/custom
      - host-dirs:/host-dirs
      - database:/database  
networks:
  back-tier: 
    external: true
volumes:
  setup-sql:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: ./setup-sql  
  db2-shell-scripts:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: ./db2-shell-scripts
  host-dirs:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: ./host-dirs
  flyway_wait_bin:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: ./flyway/wait_bin
  flyway_conf:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: ./flyway/conf
  flyway_drivers:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: ./flyway/drivers
  flyway_sql:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: ./flyway/sql
  flyway_jars:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: ./flyway/jars
  database:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: ./database
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure that this will work but I don't have enough reputation to comment:

- This is my my `automount` section in `wsl.conf`

```
[automount]
enabled = true
mountfstab = true
root = /mnt/
options = metadata,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022,fmask=11,case=off
```

- Set your `uid` and `gid` in options.
  If this does not work the next step is to add your user to the `docker` group:
  (if you don't have it already you will have to create it with `sudo groupadd docker`)

```
sudo usermod -aG docker <your-user>
```

- After this change the owner and group of the docker compose executable to your user and group to `docker`

```
sudo chown $(whoami):docker $(which docker-compose)
```

Comment: sorry for commenting after so long, but where is `docker-compose` located usually? I googled a bit but I can't find it in either `/usr/local/bin` or `~/.docker` . Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Found it in `/usr/bin` , apologies :)