# Cannot write to a Docker volume with AWS Glue image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, aws-glue

## Summary

I am using the Ubuntu image with WSL2.

I am running local tests for AWS Glue using [their Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-glue-libs), along with [LocalStack](https://www.localstack.cloud/) in a `docker-compose.yml` file. I have customised this image to create a volume between my Git repository root and the working directory of the image `/home/glue_user/workspace`.

No matter what I try, **I am unable to give the `glue_user` permissions to write in the Docker volume.** If I use the root user, everything works fine.

I need write permissions to generate a coverage report.

I know that the permissions in the container are the same as on the host system.

If I use `USER root` in my Dockerfile, then it all works fine, but I understand this is not optimal for security and would like to be able to use the bundled `glue_user` from the AWS Glue image.

The command I run to run the tests is:

```
docker compose run --build --rm glue-environment "python3 -m pytest -p no:cacheprovider --cov=aws_glue --cov-report=html"
```

## Docker

### `Dockerfile`

```
FROM amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_4.0.0_image_01

USER root
RUN chown -R glue_user /home/glue_user/workspace
USER glue_user

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install poetry

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./
RUN python3 -m poetry export -f requirements.txt --output requirements.txt --with dev --without-hashes --without-urls
RUN sed -i "/ksc/d" requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-l", "-c" ]
CMD [ "bash" ]
```

### `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
  simulated-aws:
    driver: bridge

services:
  localstack:
    networks:
      - simulated-aws
    container_name: "localstack"
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:4666:4666"            # LocalStack Gateway
      - "127.0.0.1:4610-4659:4610-4659"  # external services port range
    environment:
      - GATEWAY_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:4666
      - EXTERNAL_SERVICE_PORTS_START=4610
      - EXTERNAL_SERVICE_PORTS_END=4659
      - MAIN_CONTAINER_NAME=localstack
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG-}
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - "${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./.volume}:/var/lib/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"

  glue-environment:
    container_name: "glue-environment"
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    volumes:
      - .:/home/glue_user/workspace
    networks:
      - simulated-aws
    environment:
      - DISABLE_SSL=true
    depends_on:
      - localstack
```

## The Error

So the issue I'm trying to solve is that the glue user cannot write to the volume. I'm specifically trying to have a test coverage report written to the volume, so the error comes in as:

```
INTERNALERROR> coverage.exceptions.DataError: Couldn't use data file '/home/glue_user/workspace/.coverage.7e6e9c929f2d.1.XNeZfvkx': unable to open database file
```

## Solutions I've Tried

#### 1a) Adding glue user permissions

My Dockerfile above has:

```
USER root
RUN chown -R glue_user /home/glue_user/workspace
USER glue_user
```

Which attempts to allow the glue user access to read and write to the volume.

#### 1b) Adding glue user permissions

I've also tried using `chmod -R 0777 /home/glue_user/workspace` to allow all users permissions to read/write the directories.

#### 2a) Modifying the `/etc/wsl.conf`

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69091640/4590710) I've tried to add the following to my WSL config:

```
[automount]
root = /
options = "metadata"
```

#### 2b) Modifying the `/etc/wsl.conf`

Following [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67406155/4590710) I tried to update my WSL config to this:

```
[automount]
enabled = true
mountfstab = true
root = /mnt/
options = metadata,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022,fmask=11,case=off
```

And I also tried running the various commands Gregory Butler suggests like using `sudo usermod -aG docker <my-user>`.

#### 3) Using other working directories

I tried using a folder within the working directory like `/home/glue_user/workspace/src` or a different area entirely like `/home/app`.

#### 4) Running in a different environment

I tried running the docker-compose in a GitHub Action and got the same error, so I while I originally thought this was an issue with WSL, I am no longer sure of that.